# How to set the Datagridview cell to accept 3-digit number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is my code for accepting number only in textbox:

```
Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".", vbBack
            e.Handled = False
        Case Else
            e.Handled = True
End Select
```

Can I also use these kind of code in the cell of the datagridview?, And also how to limit the no. of characters in the cell automatically, which means there will be no msgbox to prompt the user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this piece of coding on the Editing Control of the datagridview

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
Try

    If 'Set the column/cell

         AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf TextNumberKeypress

    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    '... 
End Try
```

End Sub

```
   Sub TextNumberKeypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
   'Put the validations for your cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "'Set the column/cell

Comment: disregard my 1st comment, this is the best!, thank you sir! it really save my time :)

Comment: Its not sir,its Miss!!

Comment: Oops, Sorry Miss :) but thank you again, it really help me a lot :)